# Why does LLVM not optimize away unnecessary jmps for tail calls to the next function?

Tags: llvm, tail-call

The following LLVM IR:

```
define tailcc i64 @f() {
  %1 = musttail call tailcc i64 @g(i64 10)
  ret i64 %1
}

define tailcc i64 @g(i64 %0) align 1 optsize noinline {
  ret i64 %0
}
```

produces this X86 object code (`clang-18 -O3 test.ll -o test.o && objdump -d test.o`):

```
0000000000000000 <f>:
   0:   bf 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%edi
   5:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmp    a <g>

000000000000000a <g>:
   a:   48 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%rax
   d:   c2 08 00                ret    $0x8
```

Why is the `jmp` from `f` to `g` not optimized away? It is not needed, as `g` is immediately below `f`.

Comment: It's not a matter of why the jump is *inserted*, it's why it is *not removed*.  And you could consider weighing the cost of implementing such an optimization against its potential benefits.  It seems to me that it's possible here only because the functions happened to be adjacent, which is more or less coincidence as far as the compiler is concerned - unless you are going to try to sort functions to put tailcalls next to each other.  `-ffunction-sections` would make this optimization impossible, and I think it would complicate LTO as well.

Comment: And since the entry point of `g` would typically be aligned, even if you remove the jump you are going to have to insert some nops in its place, which may not be that much faster to execute.  And, if `g` can be inlined - which here you have artificially blocked - the whole point is moot.

Comment: @NateEldredge your comments are right, of course. In my context however, this is something that systematically appears: I am compiling from a language where almost all functions have multiple entry points. (In my example, `f` can be seen as an alternative entry point for `g` where the parameter has a default value.) This happens often enough that it seems there may be a benefit to chaining the functions together, even though you have to give up on alignment. Inlining would increase code size. I can understand that it wouldn't be the default, but it would be nice to have the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LLVM generally optimizes using passes, of which there are three kinds, passes that operate on functions being one.

LLVM tries to make it easy to write and combine passes. It would in fact be quite easy to write a pass to do what you're suggesting, but doing that would also do something else: Add a new requirement on all succeeding passes.

For example, with such a new pass, other passes cannot any longer analyse `call` and `invoke` instructions to find out which functions are called, because this new pass has added a new way to call functions, namely falling through.

Is the effect worth complicating the world? I'd have to say no, LLVM's simple interface is a valuable feature, much more valuable than eliding one assembly instruction.

Comment: Thank you. In comments above I gave some context why I think it may be worth it in my case. I am not entirely sure I understand why such a pass would make other passes more complicated. For example, would it not be possible to add a different tail kind `fallthrough`, which is like `musttail` but suggests/requires that the tailcalled function is positioned immediately below the caller? Then it would still be possible to analyze the call graph, but I don't know how complicated it would be to enforce the order in the generated code.

Comment: Certainly it would be possible. In this case it's just two more rules (and fairly difficult rules since if other passes overlook them the breakage would be difficult to spot). However, one of LLVM's strengths (in the eyes of the maintainers) is simplicity of writing passes, ie. the low number of rules passes must obey. If one considers a low number of rules desirable, then adding two rules requires strong justification, see? "It would be possible" is not a strong justification, particularly when the same gain can be had by inlining one function into the other.

Comment: BTW. One of the reasons for making it simple to write passes is that people like you should be able to write passes that are worth it for just you. Writing the necessary code would require a few tens of lines. Try it, you should find it easy. If it requires more than 30 lines, you can post a question here.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!